# Why in get() method of FirefoxDriver() driver we always need to mention http;//?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

Why in get() method of FirefoxDriver() driver I need to mention http:// E.g,driver.get("http://www.example.com"); if I dont provide http then I am getting an error.Why get() method needs http://.

```
public class OpenBrowser{

public void clickAddUser(){
    WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
    d.get("www.example.com");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OpenBrowser o =new OpenBrowser();
    o.clickAddUser();
}
```

**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Target URL www.example.com not well-formed.
Command duration or timeout: 59 milliseconds**

Comment: Because a URL requires a protocol. You are simply not used to it because browsers do that work for you when you surf the interwebz.

Comment: How would you driver know the protocol (http, https or other) otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

As per the *Selenium Java Client* **`get`** is defined in **DriverCommand** *interface* as:

```
String GET = "get";
```

The implementation of `get()` method works pretty much similar.

As an example from the *Selenium Python Client* **`get()`** method is defined as:

```
def get(self, url):
    """
    Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    """
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
```

So, `Command.GET` requires an argument of type **`url`**

As per wikipedia [**`URL`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) is the **Uniform Resource Locator (URL)** is a reference to a web resource that specifies its location on a computer network and a mechanism for retrieving it. A URL is a specific type of **Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)**. URLs occur most commonly to reference web pages ([http](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)), but are also used for file transfer ([ftp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)), email ([mailto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)), database access ([JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)), and many other applications.

Most web browsers display the URL of a web page above the page in an address bar. A typical URL could have the form http://www.example.com/index.html which indicates a **protocol** (e.g. **`http`**), a **hostname** (e.g. **`www.example.com`**), and a **file name** (e.g. **`index.html`**).

hence you need to specify all the three arguments as mentioned above.